# Is there a way to solve 'local variable 'kwargs' referenced before assignment' from __init__?

Tags: python-3.x, keyword-argument

I have a Class that takes in `**kwargs`. I want to be able to use it within a function inside the class.
I've looked at other solutions that say one must use `return self.kwargs`, but I'm not sure where I must do it (outside of the function, or inside the function but at the end)

```py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name:str, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        # print(kwargs/self.kwargs) returns the dictionary as I expected

    ## There's an __enter__ and __exit__ that does nothing, just returns self

    def show():
        if kwargs:
            print(name, f"{key} and {value}" for key, value in self.kwargs.items())    # Using kwargs.items() didn't work too

        else:
            print(name)

        return self.kwargs
```

Then I did:

```py
with Foo('some_name', foo='bar', foo_bar='baz') as f:
    f.show()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```py
  File "/...", line 73, in <module>
    f.show()
  File "/...", line 96, in show
    if kwargs:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'kwargs' referenced before assignment
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to put self.kwargs in if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things are wrong. First the function doesn’t have the class instance `self` passed into it. Second the `if` statement should be `if self.kwargs`. Which is accessing the instance’s `kwargs` variable.

```py
def show(self):
        if self.kwargs:
            print(name, f"{key} and {value}" for key, value in self.kwargs.items())    # Using kwargs.items() didn't work too

        else:
            print(name)

        return self.kwargs
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like two errors:

Your method definition needs to include self, and thereafter you can access instance variables (your kwargs) from 'self'.

```
def show(self):
    if self.kwargs...
```

When you instantiate a new object instance `FooInstance = Foo('John',...)`, you create new variables for that instance. All methods of the Foo class which require instance variables need to have a argument passed in, which is termed self by convention. You can then access instance variables using the self keyword in those methods.

The print statement looks wrong too, you'd probably want this instead

```
print(f"{self.name} {key} and {value}" for key, value in self.kwargs.items())
```

Lastly, I don't believe you need the `with ... as` context manager here. Something like this would be more appropriate.

```
myobj =  Foo(...)
myobj.show()
```